# Change all item colors from a recyclerview

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

Trying to figure out what is the issue with updating RecyclerView's Adapter.

I want to change the color of all the item from a recyclerview with a button.

When I chang the value of colorchange at the begining of the activity the recyclerview is set with the new color. But not when I change it clicking the button...

Here is my adapter :

```
class Countryadapter(
    val countries: Array<String>,
    val itemClickListener: View.OnClickListener,
    val changecolor: Boolean
)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<Countryadapter.ViewHolder>(){

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val cardView = itemView.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.card_view)
        val icon = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icon)
        val name = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val viewItem =inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_country, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(viewItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val country = countries[position]
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        holder.name.text = country
        holder.cardView.tag = position
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener)

        if (changecolor){
            holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f42069"))
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countries.size
    }

}
```

and here is my Main activity

```
var changecolor = false

    val adapter = Countryadapter(countries, this, changecolor)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.Recycler_view)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Button_1)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            changecolor = true
            Toast.makeText(this, "change color = $changecolor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }

        }
```

Comment: You need to invalidate everything by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. If you want to be able to change it back, you need to put an else statement after `if (changeColor)` to and set the default color.

Comment: Adding to @Tenfour04's comment, `changeColor` in adapter class should be mutable (`var` instead of `val`) and should be updated in button's `setOnClickListener` before calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` (instead of `recyclerView.adapter = adapter`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adapter:**

Let `changeColor` be a mutable variable. Changing its value and notifying the adapter will refresh the UI with the correct color state.

Setting the text color for both states is necessary because views get recycled on scroll and colors may mix up. This will happen in the case when a subset of items has a different color state than others.

```
class Countryadapter(
    val countries: Array<String>,
    val itemClickListener: View.OnClickListener,
    var changecolor: Boolean /* var instead of val */
)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<Countryadapter.ViewHolder>(){

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) { ... }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder { ... }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val country = countries[position]
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
        holder.name.text = country
        holder.cardView.tag = position
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener)

        if (changecolor){
            holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f42069"))
        }else{
            holder.name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK /* default color for text */)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { ... }
}
```

---

**Activity:**

After changing `adapter.changecolor` in button click `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is required to indicate that recycler view needs to refresh all it's content.

```
val adapter = Countryadapter(countries, this, false /* default state */)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.Recycler_view)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Button_1)
    button.setOnClickListener {
        adapter.changecolor = true
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        Toast.makeText(this, "change color = ${adapter.changecolor}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```